# Access a system defined environment variable in angular js (grunt)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am new to `angular js` . I am using grunt file . So, Here, In java we set environment variables and the use it like `System.getEnv("")` . Now , I have defined a system environment variable and I want to have that in the angular application code for some operation . How can I access that variable in the angular application code ? Or in the grunt file and then how to use it in the controller? thanks for the help.

Comment: _In angular I have defined an environment variable_ Please share the code

Comment: updated the question . please look

Answer (score 0):

Grunt uses Node so you can access environment vars with `process.env.[your var name]`.
Since Angular runs in the client there are no system vars.

Comment: where to include this ? I mean in the controller itself ?

Comment: Sorry but , I am totally new to this. It will be really helpful if u give some more Info

Comment: You would really need to share more context in what you are trying to achieve and what your setup looks like.